# Search with jooq if a jsonb column contains a specific value doesnt work properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, jooq

I have to create a query with jooq that checks to see if a jsonb column contains a specific value that I pass to it. I've tried doing something like this:

```
jooq.selectFrom(Tables.TRANSACTIONS_TABLE)
            .where(
                TRANSACTIONS_TABLE.MESSAGE
                    .contains(JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode().put("transactionId", transactionId))
            )
            .fetch { TransactionTable.fromRecord(it) }
```

But I'm not really sure why it's not working, it's not finding anything even that the data is there

Answer (score 0):

[`Field.contains(...)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Field.html#contains(org.jooq.Field)) only works for string types, not for JSON(B) types. You have to implement your own contains support via [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)